# Items on List View not appearing

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have an activity that contains two fragments:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eventlist);

    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getFragments());
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
}

private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    EventListFragment eventListFragment = (EventListFragment)
            EventListFragment.instantiate(this, EventListFragment.class.getName());
    EventGridFragment eventGridFragment = (EventGridFragment)
            EventGridFragment.instantiate(this, EventGridFragment.class.getName());

    fList.add(eventListFragment);
    fList.add(eventGridFragment);

    return fList;
}
```

This is my page adapter:

```
private List<Fragment> fragments;

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return fragments.get(i);
}
```

And the fragment in question:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventlist ,container, false);
    String[] x = new String[]{"AAA","BBB","CCC","AAA","BBB","CCC","AAA","BBB","CCC","AAA","BBB","CCC","AAA","BBB","CCC","AAA","BBB","CCC"};

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> test = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,x);
    listView.setAdapter(test);
    return view;
}
```

The XML file for the above fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The fragments are both being created but the ListView inside this fragment is not. I am not sure why not :/

Comment: Could we also see the XML layout file of your activity?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are overriding FragmentPagerAdapter, in that case, you don't have to override *isViewFromObject*. Try removing that method.

Comment: I copied your code fragment into my project and could see ListView :)
See my code and check the difference.
https://github.com/daisy1754/StackOverFlowListView

Comment: You can browse, download, get diff, and run my program. I didn't implement EventGridFragment, but most of code is copied from your question.

Comment: @cxzp Did you try (or at least checkout) my code? I'd like to delete the repo in a few days :-Q

Comment: yes delete the repo ... I got it working from your code and then came to the conclusion there was nothing wrong with mine. I rename d the variables and it magically started working :/